# VBA error -2147417848 y 1004 with userform y ListObject.ListRows.Add por 4 vez

Tags: excel, vba

Presento este error cuando intento ejecutar un userform por 4 vez

[image: errorvba]

```
Dim wksheet As Worksheet
Dim lotable As ListObject
Dim stName As String
Dim lrRowadd As ListRow

stName = "tPrep"

Set wksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Presupuesto")
Set lotable = wksheet.ListObjects(stName)

Set lrRowadd = lotable.ListRows.Add


With lrRowadd
    
    .Range(1).Value = Me.TBFecha
    .Range(2).Value = Me.CBSubCategoria
    .Range(3).Value = Me.TBDetalles
    .Range(4).Value = CDbl(Me.TBValor)

End With
```

en la linea
 `set lrRowadd = lotable.ListRows.Add`
el userform trabaja las 3 primeras veces, insertando lso datos correctamente pero la 4 vez, me sale el error y normalmente me reincia el excel

[image: Userform]

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a stackverflow en español por favor actualiza tu pregunta y traducela